# App won't open after clicking on remote notification'

Tags: macos, apple-push-notifications, osx-mountain-lion

I have a Problem with remote notifications and OSx 10.8.
I enabled the remote push notifications successful. They also were delivered to my system, but when I try to click one nothing happens.
Also for this app update I had to enable sandboxing!

The Mac-Console log:

```
29.08.12 11:03:50,600 usernoted[194]: Cannot find originating application to launch for event action.  file://localhost/Users/clueckler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mysms_OSX_Client-bcaianxrdhpztmdcnsrgzqdtqmvi/Build/Products/Debug/mysms_test.app/ is not the same app as the one that sent the original notification.
29.08.12 11:03:50,600 usernoted[194]: Error finding application com.mysms.osx.client.test.
```

I thought it was a problem of the AdHoc-Test or something. So I tried to submit it to the AppStore with success!
But the same problem appears with the AppStore Version (now I removed it from store ...)

Is there a solution for this problem?

EDIT (Code Information):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib { 
// Register app for remote notification 
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(NSRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | NSRemoteNotificationTypeSound | NSRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)]; 
} 

- (void)application:(NSApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 
//Post token to server 
}
```

Comment: hi can you give details as to how you implemented remote notifications support

Comment: I've edited my question above ... no solution untill now :-(

Comment: hey can u give the steps you followed to create certificate for push notifications

Comment: Did you try testing your app store version on a system you had not been debugging on?

Comment: Are you sending the action value in the payload when you send notification.

Comment: Chris, did you solve this problem?

Comment: Nope got it never to work.